# How to stop statusbar overlayping in ios 7 when rotating view

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, ios7

i am working compatablity modification for ios 7. My application view is rotating for landscape and portiate mode.

But currently in ios 7 status bar is overlayping to my view.in all rotation. I have try with following code but it not work for me.

In my appDelegate file appdidfinishlaunching i set 1 notification as follows:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(applicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation:)
name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                                   object:nil];
   }
```

This will cold method as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    int a = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey: UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] intValue];
    int w = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    int h = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    switch(a){
        case 4:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,w,h);
            break;
        case 3:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(-20,0,w-20,h+20);
            break;
        case 2:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,-20,w,h);
            break;
        case 1:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(20,0,w-20,h+20);
    }

}
```

For the first time when i launch my application status bar was over layping my view.
Secound time when i rotate my iPad at that time it set status bar black ground on the different possition.
Every time I was getting wrong.

Please help me, Am i doing anything wrong in the above.

And if possible please provide me sample code for all rotation to stop status bar overlayping.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the navigation bar from overlapping by using this code

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: Why do you think the OP is using a UINavigationController?

Comment: @adam i am not using navigation controller i just want to calculate hight and width and x,y and set frame of the view according ios 7 and it can work on all rotation.